# curl command handler

Tags: php, curl

I'm using curl in order to list posts and check its details.
Now I also want to use curl to delete certain posts.
However, I actually don't know how to handle the command below:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
```

The CURLOPT_URL which is set, do I have to add a line up there? What is actually happening there? Is there a $_REQUEST variable set now? I don't seem to understand it because I can't really imagine you can use the customrequest without handling the command.

The contents which are being listed are pulled from a database.

I'm looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a PHP program that can sensibly process an HTTP Delete request? (The cURL stuff is very focused on the client side of things, not the server side)

Comment: Alright, the list and detail data are also being outputted through curl. So shouldn't the commands work then?

Comment: What does that have to do with my question?

Comment: sorry, i have read your question too fast. But to answer it, yes i am asking how to write the delete request correctly.

Comment: Umm. If the answer is "Yes" then you are asking how to write the server side code to process the request and make a response. Do you mean "No" and that you want to know how to construct a Delete request?

Comment: Yes, i want to process the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` will tell you if the request is a *DELETE* request.

`$_REQUEST` and `$_GET` will be populated by the usual bits of data.

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will give you the URI requested if you want to figure out what to delete via some other method.

Everything else is specific to how the data you want to delete bits of is organised.

Comment: Is it also possible to handle the request or get data on a remote url?

Comment: If you mean "Can I install a PHP script on someone else's site that will allow me to delete things on that site" then no.

Comment: What i mean is, is it possible to PUT data to a remote site (i own) and how do i output the data on that remote site?

Comment: Yes. You just have to read the raw HTTP request body since it won't be parsed into `$_POST` and friends since it won't be a standard form data format.